# List<string>.Clear() vs List<string> = new List<string> in C# (possible ByReference issue?)

Tags: c#, list, .net-core, pass-by-reference

I was doing the AoC day six challenge when I noticed a bug in my program.

In the code below, when using `List<string>`.`Clear()` and the end of the loop I had 486 copies of the last `List<String>`'s values. I found a fix (hack?) but I want to know why `.Clear()` isn't working on my `List<String>`. Full program can be found [here.](https://github.com/CryptoJones/aoc2020/blob/master/D01/d01/Program.cs)

```
int result = 0;
List<List<string>> groups = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> buffer = new List<string>();
buffer.Clear();

foreach (string s in lineList)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        buffer.Add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        groups.Add(buffer);

        //// old way
        //// was getting 487 copies of the last group
        // buffer.Clear

        // new way, works but I don't understand why
        // byref vs byval issue?
        buffer = new List<string>();

    }
   
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Another solution is: `groups.Add(buffer.ToList()); buffer.Clear()` so you "clone" the `List` before adding it to `groups`. Note that the `buffer.Clear();` in the fourth line is useless. The `buffer` is already clear. And be happy, it is quite a common error that I do every couple of months. Nothing to be ashamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Clear()` doesn't create a new instance, and `Add()` *doesn't create a copy.*

So with only `buffer.Clear()`, the `else` block was adding a reference to the **same List instance** to `groups` on each iteration, which was also emptied.